# Display Redux-Form validation error for embedded component

Tags: redux, redux-form

I have embedded a React component inside of another where I have applied validation on the parent:

```
const EmailAddressInput = (props) => {
  const { emailList, onKeyUp } = props;
  return (
      <div>
        <textarea
          {...emailList}
        />
      </div>
  );
};
```

It's placed inside another component like:

```
let Emailer = (props) => {
  const { fields: { passType, invitees },

  return (
    <legend>Select pass type:</legend>
     { renderPassTypes(eventsState.selectedEvent.AssociatedPassTypes) }
     {passType.touched && passType.error && <span className="error">{passType.error}</span>}

     <EmailAddressInput { ...invitees } onKeyUp={ () => handleEmailToBarKeyUp(invitees.emailList.value) } />
                {invitees.touched && invitees.error && <span className="error">{invitees.error}</span> }
  )
}
```

Now, given I want to ensure the `EmailAddressInput`'s `emailList` is not empty, I added a custom validation rule:

```
const emailValidator = createValidator({
  invitees: [requiredProperty('emailList')],
  passType: required,
});
```

My validation utility looks like:

```
export function required(value) {
  if (isEmpty(value)) {
    return 'Required';
  }
}

export function requiredProperty(fieldName) {
  return function (value) {
    return required(value[fieldName]);
  };
}

export function createValidator(rules) {
  return (data = {}) => {
    const errors = {};
    Object.keys(rules).forEach((key) => {
      const rule = join([].concat(rules[key])); // concat enables both functions and arrays of functions
      const error = rule(data[key], data);
      if (error) {
        errors[key] = error;
      }
    });
    return errors;
  };
}
```

Now when I submit my form with the `EmailAddressInput` textarea empty, `createValidator`  returns `{invitees: 'Required'}`. The form submission is halted as expected (hooray!) but the error message is lost.

Errors are added as an `errors` property of the Redux-Form `field` object, but `invitees` isn't a `field` object, so I guess for that reason the collection of errors isn't being attached.

The `field` is actually the `emailList` textarea in `EmailAddressInput`, but that isn't getting the errors collection attached as the relevant key in the errors collection is different (`invitees` vs `emailList`)

Any idea how I can get that error displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The trick was to project the right structure from my validation rule functions:

```
export function requiredProperty(fieldName) {
  return function (value) {
    const error = required(value[fieldName]);
    if (error) {
      return { [fieldName]: error };
    }
  };
}
```